# Change Enter key press behavior on Lightning Combobox

Tags: lightning-combobox, keyboard

I am trying to override behavior of enter key-press on a LWC form.

The form has lightning-input elements and lightning-combobox elements.

So on lightning-input elements, onkeypress i am checking if the keycode is 13 and changing focus to next element. This works well.

But when focus is on lightning-combobox element, onkeypress event or onkeydown event does not call the associated Javascript handler. So the focus doesn't move to next element.

This is because - by default when focus is on lightning-combobox & when enter key is pressed, it shows the dropdown to select value.

**Is there any way to change this enter key behavior on lightning-combobox?**

*Other option i could try:*

I could use the onchange event on lightning-combobox, but if the user doesn't change the default value then the onchange event doesn't get called.

**Is there an onselect event that i can use?**(assuming user will use keyboard enter key or mouse, this can fire-off the javascript handler to change the focus)

Comment: You could use my MultiSelect component (which can be configured to be single select). Then it's just the addition of a little bit of code and it's all hunky dory. https://github.com/rapsacnz/MultiSelect

Comment: Why are you breaking the standard rules of UX? Tab should move between elements, Enter submits the form.

Comment: Thanks @CasparHarmer, i will try it out.

Comment: @sfdcfox - End users are very much used to hitting Enter key in current application. But point noted.